# Messenger account linking authentication flow in Django

Tags: python, django, facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

How can I complete the authentication flow of the account linking in Django?

I send the login template to user. When the user clicks on it, she is redirect to https://example.ngork.io/authenticate with the parameters account_linking_token and redirect_uri.

Now, when I perform the redirection I have this error:

Page not found (404)

Request URL:    http://example.ngrok.io/[redirect_uri]

1. ^admin/
2. ^$ [name='index']
3. ^messengerhook [name='messengerhook']
4. ^authenticate [name='authenticate']

The current URL didn't march any of these.

EDIT:

the url of the server is generated by ngork since I run it in local.

```
https://a0505537.ngrok.io
```

The redirect uri is the one provided by facebook for linking account flow:

```
https://www.facebook.com/messenger_platform/account_linking
      ?account_linking_token=ACCOUNT_LINKING_TOKEN
      &authorization_code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE
```

About the views, in the question there are the urls written in my urls.py setting file.

Basically, the authenticate view is a login button and when the user is logged I run `window.location.replace(["redirect_uri"])`

RESOLVED:

The url wasn't decoded, so I add:

```
var url = decodeURIComponent(params["redirect_uri"]);
```

Comment: Put your urls and views in question.

Comment: the url of the server is generated by ngork since I run it in local. The redirect uri is the one provided by facebook for linking account flow:
https://www.facebook.com/messenger_platform/account_linking
      ?account_linking_token=ACCOUNT_LINKING_TOKEN
      &authorization_code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE

Comment: Look at that `/[redirect_uri]`, your redirect url is not generating. That's why the code is essential.

Comment: what is not generating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. Details are in the question after the tag RESOLVED